# Are there any advantages to a nested If/Else instead of Else If's?

Tags: javascript, performance, language-agnostic, conditional-statements

I came across this unique practice in a browser detection script.

```
if (/MSIE/.test(_3)) {
    IE = true;
} else {
    if (/AppleWebKit/.test(_3)) {
        Safari = true;
    } else {
        if (/Opera/.test(_3)) {
            Opera = true;
        } else {
            if (/Camino/.test(_3)) {
                Camino = true;
            } else {
                if (/Firefox/.test(_3) || /Netscape/.test(_3) || ) {
                    Mozilla = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any advantages to using this nested If/Else method?

What if I just changed it to:

```
 if (){
 } else if (){
 } else if (){
 } else if (){
 }
```

Would it run slower or anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case the `switch` statement could also be used? Something like:

```
switch ((_3).match(/msie|applewebkit|opera|camino|firefox/i)[0]) {
  case 'MSIE' : /* ...; */ break;
  case 'AppleWebKit' : /* ...; */ break;
  /* ... etc. */
  default: BrowserCouldntBeDetermined = true;
}
```

I adhere to the previous answer: else if() is equivalent to but more readable then else { if () ...}

Anyway, the code you found and presented looks a bit clumsy and not really fast for other reasons than the way `if...else` is used. Concerning the meaning of the code (and aside from the question), a better way to take care of browser differences is by [object detection](http://developer.apple.com/internet/webcontent/objectdetection.html) I would say.

Answer (score 11):

It won't change anything other than the indentation and readability. Still the same code, absolutely equivalent :-) I would definitely change it though as it would make it more readable. Indentation usually means nesting whereas here there's no nesting.

Answer (score 5):

This is known as "[the arrow anti-pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrowAntiPattern)" (due to the resemblance to an arrowhead) ...

```
 if
   if
     if
       if
         do something
       endif
     endif
   endif
 endif
```

..  and it's almost always bad for readability, unless there is some compelling reason to leave it.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html

I would flatten it.